# Selecting text in more than one column without selecting both lines?

Tags: visual-mode

Is it possible to selecting text in more than one column without selecting both lines in VIM?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here...

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do? It is not clear in this question I think you're looking for visual block mode but I'm not sure. EDIT: CarpetSmoker the Lucky Luke of comments was faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-V`, then arrows (or hjkl) starts block/column selection mode - is that the feature you are looking for?